# Assigning onClick to Dynamic Buttons with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where I am creating one button in each row dynamically. So if we have 3 rows, we will have 3 buttons at the 3rd column of each row.

I am facing a problem at two levels :

i) Assigning a single function that will be called at 'onClick' of all the buttons.
ii) Reading the values of the corresponding columns of the button which has been pressed, 
for example : Say we have 3 columns, and I press the button at the 2nd row , 3rd column, I need to read the values of the 2nd row, 1st and 2nd column.

The entire thing is built up dynamically.

Here is the table:

```
<body>
    <div id="up"></div>
    <table id = "tab" style="width:500px">
        <tr>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
            <th>Session Activity</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
             <?php
                    $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
                    $client = $_SESSION["Client"];
                    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345', 'MyDB');
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                        echo "<option value='".'0'."'>".'Connection Error'."</option>";
                        exit();
                    }else{
                        $res=mysqli_query($con, "select * from TL_Session_Notes Where Uid = '".$uid."' AND CName = '".$client."'");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td>".$row['Sn_date'].'/'.$row['Sn_time']."</td><td>".$row['Sn_activity']."</td>".
                            "<td id = '"."openBtns"."'><input type='"."button"."' class = '"."btns"."' value = '"."Open Session Note"."' action = '"."OpenSession()"."'/>"."</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    mysqli_close($con);
             ?>
    </table>
    <div id="down"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the code I've tried to get the (i) part working :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("openBtns").on('click', '.btns', function() {
                OpenSession();
            });
        });
        function OpenSession(){
            window.location.replace('Sessions.php');
        }
</script>
```

Need some help on how to do this and where is my approach going wrong.

Comment: You have multiple elements with id openBtns? Also you are doing unnecessary string concatenations (overuse of the . operator).

Comment: Any way of using different ids for different elements when elements are created dynamically ?

Comment: You dont need those id:s, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenSession(date, time, activity)
    {
/* here we can do something creative with the arguments date, time and activity */
            window.location.replace('Sessions.php');
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="up"></div>
    <table id="tab" style="width:500px">
        <tr>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
            <th>Session Activity</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
<?php
        output_rows();
?>
    </table>
    <div id="down"></div>
</body>

<?php
function output_rows()
{
    $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
    $client = $_SESSION["Client"];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345', 'MyDB');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "<option value='0'>Connection Error</option>";
    }else{
        $name = mysql_escape_string($name);
        $client = mysql_escape_string($client);
        $res=mysqli_query($con, "select * from TL_Session_Notes Where Uid='$uid' AND CName='$client'");

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $date = $row['Sn_date'];
            $time = $row['Sn_time'];
            $activity = $row['Sn_activity'];

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$date/$time</td><td>$activity</td>";              
                echo "<td><input type='button' class='btns' value='Open Session Note' onclick='OpenSession(\"$date\", \"$time\", \"$activity\")' /></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, there isn't any $name param there. The rest is fine. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `td.openBtns` is added dynamically too. You have to use a selector which is static/non-dynamic.

Looks like `#tab` is the one you want.

```
$("#tab").on('click', '.btns', function() {
    OpenSession();
});
```

or try

```
$(document).on('click', '.btns', function() {
    OpenSession();
});
```

Comment: @Priyabrata - can you please create a jsfiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: @Priyabrata - use `$(document)`.. see updated answer.

Comment: Difficult to do a JSFiddle, for I need to create the rows dynamically with data.

Answer (score 1):

The selector `$("openBtns")` is taking all `<openBtns>` elements

Since you have a table with id "openBtns", you need to add `#` before the id.

```
$("#openBtns").on('click', '.btns', function() {
       OpenSession();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should address the second part of your request.

`$('.openBtns').on('click', '.btns', function () {
        var td1 = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
        var td2 = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').text()
        alert(td1 + ' ' + td2);
    });`